# C++ virtual method problem

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have two structs, in which I'm trying to overwrite a method in the base struct.

The base struct is defined as:

```
 template <class T>
 struct compareFunction : public std::binary_function<T,T,bool> {
    virtual bool operator() (const T & first, const  T & second) {
        //This function is always called
        return first < second;
    }
 };
```

The struct I'm attempting to subclass with is defined as:

```
template <class Key, class T>
struct valuecomparer : public compareFunction<std::pair<Key,T> > {
    std::binary_function<Key, Key,bool> comparer;

    bool operator() (const std::pair<Key, T>& x, const std::pair<Key, T> & y) {
            //This function is never called
            Key tx = x.first;
            Key ty = y.first;
            if(tx < ty) {
               return true;
            } else {
               return false;
            }
    }
};
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ideally, the method in valuecomparer would be called instead of the method in compareFunction.

It is being called basically like this (not necessarily valid syntax,but trying to get idea across):

```
typedef compareFunction<T> cmpType; //Inside a class definition, T is std::pair<int,double>
valuecomparer<int,double> compareVar;
compareVar.comparer = std:less<int>();
cmpType x = compareVar;
x.compare(std::pair<int,double>(8,20.0),std::pair<int,double>(8,25.0));
```

Apparently after switching the storage from a pure struct to a struct pointer in the class that is using the base struct (and consequently derived struct), everything works.  Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @Seth: The overriden subclass function is never called it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code you've posted, in order to have a overridden derived class' function to be called, you **MUST** call it from a pointer or reference to the base class type, not an object whose type is of the base class itself.  So when you create code like this:

```
cmpType x = compareVar;
x(std::pair<int,double>(8,20.0),std::pair<int,double>(8,25.0));
```

that's always going to call the function definition in the base-class since there is no function that can be used for the polymorphic derived function call.  The copy-constructor only copies over the v-table entries and associated members from the base-class.  So when you call a method on an object of the base-class type, even if you've created that object from a copy of a derived class, you still end up with the base-class method calls.  You would have to-do something like this:

```
cmpType& x = compareVar;
x(std::pair<int,double>(8,20.0),std::pair<int,double>(8,25.0));
```

Now when the `operator()` method is called on `x`, the correct v-table entry is used, that is the overridden version of `operator()` inside of `valuecomparer`.

Comment: I didn't even see if this is right, but +1 for length and the effort it required.

Comment: This is not correct - only a single type is passed to the base template, that of `pair<Key, T>`.

Comment: `struct valuecomparer : public compareFunction<Key>` -- this is wrong, now the `operator()` of the base class looks like `bool operatr()(Key const& left, Key const& right`, but the derived class wants `pair`s to compare.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed the post ... thanks for pointing out any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, from your pseduo-code, you're slicing your comparer:

```
typedef compareFunction<T> cmpType; //Inside a class definition, T is std::pair<int,double>
valuecomparer<int,double> compareVar;
compareVar.comparer = std:less<int>();
cmpType x = compareVar;                     // *** SLICED HERE ****
x.compare(std::pair<int,double>(8,20.0),std::pair<int,double>(8,25.0));
```

The easiest solution, given the context, would be the change the declaration of `x` to be a reference to `cmpType`, instead of a full-blown instance.

**Edit:**
Looking closer, the above will not work, at all (you said it was psuedo), but given the intent, looks like you've meant:

```
valuecomparer<int,double> compareVar;
compareVar.comparer = std:less<int>();
compareFunction<pair<int, double> > x = compareVar;                     // *** SLICED HERE ****
x.compare(std::pair<int,double>(8,20.0),std::pair<int,double>(8,25.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your `valuecomparer` for a `std::map`, then you're missing the fact that an item in the map is defined as `std::pair<const Key, Val>`. See the `const` part? :) Add that to your `std::pair<>`s. If that isn't the problem, report back where and how you actually use those functors.